# How to populate form helper select with array?

Tags: php, forms, cakephp, view, controller

I have the following array data that is being fetched from a table that isn't mine.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [sys_sbu] => Array
                (
                    [sbu_id] => EO
                    [sbu_name] => Executive Officer
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [sys_sbu] => Array
                (
                    [sbu_id] => FIN
                    [sbu_name] => Finance
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [sys_sbu] => Array
                (
                    [sbu_id] => G01
                    [sbu_name] => TEST GROUP
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [sys_sbu] => Array
                (
                    [sbu_id] => MAF
                    [sbu_name] => Medical Affairs
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [sys_sbu] => Array
                (
                    [sbu_id] => PCS
                    [sbu_name] => Patient Care Services
                )

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [sys_sbu] => Array
                (
                    [sbu_id] => SSS
                    [sbu_name] => Strategic Support Services
                )

        )

)
```

Basically, the table `sys_sbu` has 2 columns. `sbu_id` and `sbu_name`. Using the following code on my view doesn't seem to yield the expected result.

```
echo $this->Form->input('Groups', array(
    'type'=>'select',
    'options' => $groups)
);
```

[image]

What I want to happen is the value of each `select` option will be the `sbu_id` while the ones being displayed to the selection is the `sbu_name`. Like so:

```
<select>
  <option value="EO">Executive Officer</option>
  <option value="FIN">Finance</option>
  <option value="etc">etc</option>
</select>
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, a `$this->YourModel->find('list')` would return the appropriate array if your `displayField` and `primaryKey` are set correctly in the model definition.

If for some reason they're not, you have to manually adjust your select array to look like this

```
array(
    [id1] => name1,
    [id2] => name2,
    etc
)
```

<strike>But do look into [find('list')](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html), because on 95% of the cases, it solves this kind of "problem".</strike>
Just re-read that it is not your table, so I guess you're not doing a find at all. The solution remains, though, do a for in the array you're getting from the other table and adjust it like I indicated before, ids as keys, names as values

Comment: Thank you very much. You are a ray of light among these deadlined times. I did use the `primaryKey` and `displayField` approach. It isn't my table but I made a model for it.